# Snake game follow tail

Tags: python, pygame

So in my snake game using pygame, I have set the snake to be able to eat the apple and become longer but I want it to instead make a trail following the snake head instead of there being a long line behind the head.

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
import random

pygame.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (159, 218, 64)
RED =  (199, 55, 47)

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 608

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Best Snake game in existance")

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
input_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)

RandomX = random.randint(0,screen_width-32)

RandomY = random.randint(0,screen_height-32)


#Checking to make sure apple does not spawn on top of player
while RandomX == 0  and RandomY == 0:
    RandomX = random.randint(0,screen_width-32)

    RandomY = random.randint(0,screen_height-32)
while RandomX % 32 != 0:
    RandomX = random.randint(0,screen_width-32)
while RandomY % 32 != 0:
    RandomY = random.randint(0,screen_height-32)

print(RandomX,RandomY)
Snake_Player = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 32, 32)
global Apple
Apple = pygame.Rect(RandomX,RandomY,32,32)

StartingX = 0
StartingY = 0
Movement_Speed = 32
global Apple_Count
Apple_Count = 0
global Snake_Alive
Snake_Alive = True
global running
running = True
current_direction = ""
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
global Apple_Eaten_Check
Apple_Eaten_Check = False




def Make_Snake_Longer():
    for x in range(0,Apple_Count):
        if current_direction == 'RIGHT':
            Last_X = Snake_Player[0]-(32*x)

            Last_Movement = pygame.Rect(Last_X,Snake_Player[1],32,32)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,Last_Movement)
        elif current_direction == 'LEFT':
            Last_X = Snake_Player[0]+(32*x)

            Last_Movement = pygame.Rect(Last_X,Snake_Player[1],32,32)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,Last_Movement)
        elif current_direction == 'DOWN':
            Last_Y = Snake_Player[1]-(32*x)

            Last_Movement = pygame.Rect(Snake_Player[0],Last_Y,32,32)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,Last_Movement)
        elif current_direction == 'UP':
            
            Last_Y = Snake_Player[1]+(32*x)

            Last_Movement = pygame.Rect(Snake_Player[0],Last_Y,32,32)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,Last_Movement)
def New_Apple_Coordinates():
    global Apple
    RandomX = random.randint(0,screen_width)
    RandomY = random.randint(0,screen_height)
    while RandomX == 0  and RandomY == 0:
        RandomX = random.randint(0,screen_width-32)

        RandomY = random.randint(0,screen_height-32)
    while RandomX % 32 != 0:
        RandomX = random.randint(0,screen_width-32)
    while RandomY % 32 != 0:
        RandomY = random.randint(0,screen_height-32)
    Apple = pygame.Rect(RandomX,RandomY,32,32)
    Draw_Apple()

def Draw_Apple():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,Apple)
    pygame.display.update()

def Apple_Eaten():

    global Apple_Count, Apple_Eaten_Check,Apple
    Apple_Eaten_Check = True
    Apple_Count += 1
    New_Apple_Coordinates()

    

def Check_Boundries():
    global StartingX, StartingY,Snake_Alive
    if StartingX < 0:
        StartingX = 0
        Snake_Loss()
    elif StartingY < 0:
        StartingY = 0
        Snake_Loss()
    elif StartingX > screen_width - Movement_Speed:
        StartingX = screen_width  - Movement_Speed
        Snake_Loss()
    elif StartingY > screen_height - Movement_Speed:
        StartingY = screen_height  - Movement_Speed
        Snake_Loss()





def Snake_Loss():
    global running,Snake_Alive
    Snake_Alive = False
    LossScreen = pygame.Rect(200,150,400,300)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, LossScreen)
    pygame.display.update()
    

def move_snake():
    global Snake_Player, StartingX, StartingY, current_direction,Snake_Alive,Apple_Count
    if Snake_Alive:
        if current_direction == "UP":
            StartingY -= Movement_Speed

            Check_Boundries()

            if Snake_Player.colliderect(Apple):
                Apple_Eaten()

        elif current_direction == "DOWN":
            StartingY += Movement_Speed

            Check_Boundries()

            if Snake_Player.colliderect(Apple):
                Apple_Eaten()

        elif current_direction == "LEFT":
            StartingX -= Movement_Speed

            Check_Boundries()

            if Snake_Player.colliderect(Apple):
                Apple_Eaten()

        elif current_direction == "RIGHT":
            StartingX += Movement_Speed

            Check_Boundries()

            if Snake_Player.colliderect(Apple):
                Apple_Eaten()
    
    Snake_Player = pygame.Rect(StartingX, StartingY, 32, 32)


def handle_events():
    global current_direction,Snake_Alive
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if Snake_Alive:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w and current_direction != "DOWN":
                    current_direction = "UP"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s and current_direction != "UP":
                    current_direction = "DOWN"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a and current_direction != "RIGHT":
                    current_direction = "LEFT"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and current_direction != "LEFT":
                    current_direction = "RIGHT"

while running:
    if Snake_Alive:
        screen.fill(GREEN)
        pygame.display.update()
    handle_events()
    move_snake()
    Draw_Apple()

    if Apple_Count == 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,Apple)
        pygame.display.update()
    if Apple_Eaten_Check:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,Apple)
        pygame.display.update()
        Apple_Eaten_Check = False

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, Snake_Player)
    Make_Snake_Longer()
    pygame.display.update()
    sleep(0.15)
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

My only idea to fix this was to add a sleep for when the blocks behind the snakes moves but that did not work

Comment: You must save the past positions of the head in a list, then put the body parts in the positions saved in the list